# Can we use domain name instead of ip address in android

Tags: android

I am using domain name to call my rest web service being hosted in google app engine through my android app.But there comes 404 not found exception.

So can we use domain name instead of defining ip address of remote server.

Comment: yes. you can use domain instead of ip.

Comment: yes you can. if you share some code example we can help.

Comment: What happens if you access the same URL via your web browser? This can help you to find out whether the error is in the URL or in your software.

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: Thanks for support guys.. Here is my code first LocationServerRequest  class and second RestWebserviceCaller class

Comment: When I access the same through web browser it works perfectly

Answer (score -1):

```
public class LocationServerRequest {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LocationServerRequest.class);
private static final String TAG = LocationServerRequest.class.getSimpleName();

ProgressDialog progressDialog;
public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 1000 * 15;
private static final String JSON = ".json";

public LocationServerRequest(Context context) {
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");

}


public void fetchHolidayPackageLocationInBackground(LocationCallBackResponse locationCallBackResponse) {
    progressDialog.show();
    new fetchHolidayPackageLocationAsyncTask(locationCallBackResponse).execute();
}

public class fetchHolidayPackageLocationAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, LocationResponse> {

    LocationCallBackResponse locationCallBackResponse;

    public fetchHolidayPackageLocationAsyncTask(LocationCallBackResponse locationCallBackResponse) {
        this.locationCallBackResponse = locationCallBackResponse;
    }

    @Override
    protected LocationResponse doInBackground(Void... params) {
        final String HOLIDAY_PACKAGE_LOCATION = ApiServerAddress.API_URL_HOLIDAY_PACKAGE + Url.AgentAPIUrls_V1.HOLIDAY_PACKAGE_LOCATION + JSON ;
        LocationResponse locationResponse = null;
        RestRequestWrapper restRequestWrapper = new RestRequestWrapper("toc","api",null,HOLIDAY_PACKAGE_LOCATION,"",LocationResponse.class, HTTPREQUESTMETHOD.POST);
        try {
            RestWebServiceCaller restWebServiceCaller = new RestWebServiceCaller();
            LocationResponse response = (LocationResponse) restWebServiceCaller.processRequest(restRequestWrapper);
            LOGGER.info("RESULT : "+response);
        }catch (Exception e){
            LOGGER.error("Something went wrong while getting response : ",e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return locationResponse;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(LocationResponse locationResponse) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        locationCallBackResponse.fetchHolidayPackageLocation(locationResponse);
        super.onPostExecute(locationResponse);
    }
}

}
```

---

```
public class RestWebServiceCaller {
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RestWebServiceCaller.class);

Object result = null;
HttpURLConnection urlConnection;

public Object processRequest(RestRequestWrapper restRequestWrapper) throws Exception {
    try{
        URL url = new URL(restRequestWrapper.getUrl());
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);///*milliseconds*/
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);/* milliseconds */

        //make some HTTP header nicety
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Host", "android.schoolportal.gr");

        int responseCode = -1;
        LOGGER.info("Calling --> " + restRequestWrapper.getProvider() + " :- " + restRequestWrapper.getOperation());
        LOGGER.info("API URL --> " + restRequestWrapper.getUrl());
        switch (restRequestWrapper.getHttprequestmethod()) {
            case GET:
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
                break;
            case POST:
                urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                /*DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
                // 5.3 Copy Content "JSON" into
                mapper.writeValue(wr, restRequestWrapper.getRequestObject());
                // 5.4 Send the request
                wr.flush();

                // 5.5 close
                wr.close();*/
                    if(restRequestWrapper.getRequestObject() != null){
                        OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
                        os.write(restRequestWrapper.getRequestObject().toString().getBytes());
                        os.flush();//clean up
                    }
                responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
                break;
        }
        LOGGER.info("Response Code : " + responseCode);
        LOGGER.info("Response Message : " + urlConnection.getResponseMessage());
        if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();
            LOGGER.info(response.toString());
            result = mapper.readValue(response.toString(), restRequestWrapper.getResponseClass());
            return result;
        }else{
            BufferedReader errorBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getErrorStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer errorResponse = new StringBuffer();
            while ((inputLine = errorBufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                errorResponse.append(inputLine);
            }
            errorBufferedReader.close();
            LOGGER.error("Error Message from API : ",errorResponse.toString());
        }
    }catch(Exception ex){
        LOGGER.error("Exception occurred in calling rest web service : ", ex);
    } finally {
        //urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return  result;
}
}
```